# Appcelerator IOS background while app is running or SyncTask?

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

my question for IOS only

i need to start new thread ( `background` ) have nothing with `UI` or start background service while application is running in `IOS` how ?

I've tried `Ti.worker` but its not background thread its foreground thread .

the reason i need this request i dealing with `Ti.Contacts.getAllPeople()` , and some phones has over 5K contacts and when i loop over 5K contacts the `UI` got lagged and stop working until loop is complete .

is there anyway to loop `Ti.Contacts.getAllPeople()` as pagenation or in background or thread when app is running ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use web workers like suggested here: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/117199/how-to-create-multithreading-in-mobile-sdk#answer-257976